# PHPの文字列は配列と同じように振る舞うのですか

Tags: php

**文字列は配列と同じように振る舞うのですか？**
・12はインデックス？
・それともバイト数か何か？
・{}は文字列を展開している？？

```
$a ="stackoverflow";
echo $a{12}; //w
echo $a[12]; //w
```

Comment: "PHP における文字列型は、バイトの配列と整数値 (バッファ長) "と言語リファレンス　文字列型の詳細に書かれています。
http://php.net/manual/ja/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"PHP における文字列型は、バイトの配列と整数値 (バッファ長) "と言語リファレンス　文字列型の詳細に書かれています。 http://php.net/manual/ja/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.details

> ・12はインデックス？ ・それともバイト数か何か？

12はインデックス（バイト単位）です。

> ・{}は文字列を展開している？？

展開していますが、あえて使うなら `[]`で、また、`mb_substr(),substr()` を使用することをお勧めします。

奇をてらう使い方ではなく、基本的なPHPでの波括弧の使い方を
・文字列内での変数展開時使用：変数の前後に、スペースが無いと変数名が判別できないので、変数名を明確にする為に波括弧を使用します

例、

```
○   $sting0 = ”晴天”; $string1 = "本日は{$string0}なり";
○   $sting0 = ”晴天”; $string1 = "本日は $string0 なり";

×   $sting0 = ”晴天”; $string1 = "本日は$string0なり";
```

・if文で,複数行の処理をまとめる為に使用

例、

```
if(1) 処理１

if(1) {
 処理１
 処理２
 処理３
 処理４
}
```

・ただ、複数行を囲み処理単位を明確にする（後で自分が見て直ぐに判るようにする。Objectになるわけではありません。if文と同じでスコープが変わることはありません。）

```
{
 処理１
 処理２
 処理３
}
```